# R: problemas com sort (NA)

Tags: r, classificação

Tenho um vector que quero ordenar usando `sort` mas, ao fazê-lo, não me aparecem os valores omissos (`NA`). Como fazer? Grato.

```
> x
 [1] "b" "c" "a" NA  NA  "b" "c" "a" NA  NA  "b" "c" "a"
> sort(x)
[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta fazer da seguinte forma, usando `na.last=FALSE` para os valores omissos surgirem no início, `na.last=TRUE` para surgirem no final, sendo que `na.last=NA` é o valor por omissão deste parâmetro:

```
> x
 [1] "b" "c" "a" NA  NA  "b" "c" "a" NA  NA  "b" "c" "a"
> sort(x, na.last = FALSE)
 [1] NA  NA  NA  NA  "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
> sort(x, na.last = TRUE)
 [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" NA  NA  NA  NA 
> sort(x, na.last = NA)
[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
```

Answer (score 3):

Se você usar a função `order`, o padrão é `na.last = T`.
Então da seguinte maneira funcionaria:

```
> x <- c("c", "a", NA, "b")
> x[order(x)]
[1] "a" "b" "c" NA
```

Assim como na resposta do Alexandre, você pode colocar os NA's na frente usando:

```
> x[order(x, na.last = F)]
[1] NA  "a" "b" "c"
```

Acredito que a resposta do @Alexandre é melhor, este é apenas um outro jeito de fazer!